# How to define the default value for @QueryParam?

Tags: java, jax-rs

When I add the default value of the string in JAX-RS, it doesn't take the value. It stays to null or empty.

```
@QueryParam("status")
private String status = "confirmed";
```

When I pass the status as empty or `null` or undefined it stays as empty or `null` or undefined. It doesn't take the default as confirmed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`@DefaultValue`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) annotation to specify the *default value* of the request meta-data that is bound to [`@PathParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/PathParam.html), [`@QueryParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/QueryParam.html), [`@MatrixParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/MatrixParam.html), [`@CookieParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/CookieParam.html), [`@FormParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/FormParam.html) and [`@HeaderParam`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/HeaderParam.html) annotations:

```java
@QueryParam("status")
@DefaultValue("confirmed")
private String status;
```

If a method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property is not annotated with [`@DefaultValue`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) and the corresponding meta-data is not present in the request, the value will be:

- An empty collection for `List`, `Set` or `SortedSet`.
- `null` for other object types;
- Java-defined default for primitive types.

Comment: I'm curious to know why it doesn't take the value if I assign  status = "confirmed"?

Comment: @Udhaya From the Javadoc: _"If this annotation is not used and the corresponding meta-data is not present in the request, the value will be an empty collection for `List`, `Set` or `SortedSet`, `null` for other object types, and the Java-defined default for primitive types."_

Comment: Thanks @Cassio Mazzochi Molin